# I can't access the desktop of ec2 G2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, nomachine-nx

I am try using NX to remotely connect my aws ec2 instance in the cloud. The OS is ubuntu 14.04. Following the tutorial [enter link description here](http://activeintelligence.org/blog/archive/remote-graphical-linux-desktop-on-ec2/), I can access the login page of ubuntu.

I use a new created username and password to login. BUT I am stuck because everytime I type the usename and password and press the 'Enter', nothing happened except that I was throw to the login page again.

I ensure the usename and password are correct. I have no idea now. Any suggestion?

Comment: What version of the NX server are you running?

Comment: The latest deb package, NX 4, I download from the [https://www.nomachine.com/download/linux&id=1]

Answer (score 0):

The guide you are following works for NX 3. NX 4 uses a different protocol (NX native protocol) which uses different ports than ssh.

By default NX 4 protocol uses port 4000. Make sure to open those ports on your EC2 security group.

Ps: I don't think NX 4 is going to work as you expect since you won't be able to create a virtual desktop. Try following the guide and use NX 3.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have used VNC instered.